# How can I create outward-curving border radius?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm trying to create a `div` with a curviness on the top left and top right corners. I have tried some code and couldn't achieve the same curviness and also I don't want to have 2 `div` which is restricted since it increases the `DOM`. I'm in search of the following solutions

1. I want the curviness as same as in the image
2. Im restricted to use only one `div`
   Please refer the code below.  Also please refer the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ohu7xdt/)

   ```css
   .outer{
     overflow: hidden;
     padding: 10px;
     overflow: hidden;
   }
   .inner{
     background: #fff;
     border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
     border-radius: 5px;
     width: 100px;
     height: 40px;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     position: relative;
     border-top: none;
   }
   .inner:before,.inner:after{
       content: '';
       position: absolute;
       height: 10px;
       width: 10px;
       top: -8px;
       left: -6px;
       border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
       background: #fff;
       transform: rotate(41deg);
   }
   .inner:after{
     left: auto;
     right: -6px;
      transform: rotate(-41deg);
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="outer">
     <div class="inner"> Test</div>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: Use `border-radius-top-left`, `border-radius-top-right`, and so on to have different curves at each corner.

Comment: @Barmar `border-top-left-radius`